# Multiselect option selection for a given comma separated value in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a comma separated value I need to set that value as selected in a multiselect dropdown box in jQuery. I have tried the below code, but it is not working.

```
var selectedproject = ($xml.find('SelectedProjects').text());
$("#selProj option").each(function () {
    this.selected = (this.text == selectedproject);
});
```

this is my dropdown box

```
<select id="selProj" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
    <asp:Repeater ID="repProject" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <option value="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProjectId") %>">
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProjectName") %>
            </option>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</select>
```

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Please write your html also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `split()` to turn the comma separated string in to an array. From there you can use `indexOf` to determine if the value of the `option` exists in the array and select it. Try this:

```
var selectedProjects = $xml.find('SelectedProjects').text().split(',');
$("#selProj option").each(function () {
    this.selected = selectedProjects.indexOf(this.text) != -1;
});
```